# How to get random pointer form list of pointers?

Tags: c++, stl

How to get random pointer form list of pointers ?
I have simple custom `class Buildings` and list

```
std::list<Buidldings*> temp;
```

size of temp is greater than zero. How to get random pointer from list ( 0 - temp.size)?

Comment: You could advance an iterator a random amount (as long as it's still in the list).

Comment: The point is to use a pointer to pointers, then make that pointer point to a pointer at a random point berween the first pointer and the last pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's a mouthful - I won't understand that without a tutorial. Got any pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) to pick an appropriate index and then [advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) an iterator:

```
assert( !temp.empty() );
std::list<Buidldings*>::const_iterator it = temp.begin();
std::advance( it, std::rand() % temp.size() );
Buidldings *p = *it;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
template<typename ContainerType >
typename ContainerType::iterator get_random(ContainerType & container)
{
    ContainerType::iterator iter = container.begin(); 
    std::advance(iter,rand() %container.size());
    return iter ;
}

template<typename ContainerType >
typename ContainerType::const_iterator get_random(const ContainerType & container)
{
... (same as above)
}
```

From [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/438564-access-random-item-in-stdlist/)

Comment: The `random` argument isn't used at all; intentional?

Comment: serves me right for copy pasting.. all the solutions in the gamedev post use the same style.. did advance specification change from c++03 to c++11?

Comment: @KarthikT No, it didn't, the linked code has always been incorrect. Though in C++11, we can just `return std::next(list.begin(), rand()%list.size());`.

Comment: You could also provide the same template again, but taking `const T &` and returning `T::const_iterator`. And you could rename the parameter to `container` rather than `list`, your code is sufficiently generic.

Comment: @ChristianRau, thanks, i was not aware of that function, i guess thats the function those ppl in the gamedev article wanted. 
SteveJessop, those are very valid points, have made the changes to the code

Comment: Combining the const/non-const with what Christian says, I think the exciting C++11 version is `template<typename C> auto get_random(C &c) -> decltype(c.begin()) { return std::next(c.begin(), rand() % c.size()); }`. Then you don't need to treat const specially.